# Why is there a limit to the number of reviews you can do in a day?

Tags: discussion

I'm getting

> Thank you for reviewing 20 First Posts today; come back in 1 hour to continue reviewing.

Why is there a limit on this? Doesn't reviewing help the community overall and as such should be encouraged without limits?

Cheers,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Limiting the number of votes, reviews, etc. ensures a rotation and representative view. Reviews take multiple votes to actually complete, so this helps reduce the scenario of a few people doing all of them.

Comment: Oh? But if it takes multiple people, why have it at all then? How many people does it take to do 'accept' a question?

Comment: It takes multiple people viewing an item to clear it from the review queue.